# Could the Russian Federation really have tested a nuclear weapon without anyone noticing?

Tags: russian-federation, nuclear-weapons, conspiracy-theories

In an [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q9BiuN9p8s&t=82s) with Kurbanova Live, Russian blogger and a former political scientist [Valery Solovei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valery_Solovei) has made the claim that the Russian Federation has performed a test of a nuclear weapon on November 6th, 2022.  The key elements of the claim are (the video is in Russian, but I'll summarize):

- attempts to conduct the test have been going on all throughout October-November
- 6 previous attempted tests have failed
- the 7th attempt at a test was successful
- the failures of the 1st 6 attempts have raised suspicions of sabotage

I have a difficult time understanding how a test could go unnoticed.  It is my understanding that both the radiation and the seismic consequences would be immediately registered if a test took place.  Yet I don't see anywhere anyone making similar claims.  I have looked through the news and made some Google searches.  I don't see anything about any nuclear tests on, or around, the 6th of November of 2022.

Solovei does have a history of making very provocative claims about inside knowledge of Russian elites.  He was a professor at the [MGIMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_State_Institute_of_International_Relations), which trains future Russian diplomats.  So he could *potentially* have real insider knowledge.  But I am tempted to dismiss this as just another attempt to raise his clout by claiming an insider knowledge on a "sexy" topic (nuclear weapons).

Is there any chance whatsoever his claim can be true though?  Is it possible that the Russian Federation has conducted this test and no one has noticed?

Comment: This is a technical question, not a political question.  I'm not sure what the right place for it is, but while there is a political context, and the answer may be of interest to politicians, the question itself isn't political. This question can't be answered by a "political expert", but but an expert in nuclear testing: So perhaps [physics.se] or, since it involves seismology [earthscience.se]  My understanding is that even small nuclear weapons have a distinctive seismic signature. [skeptics.se] is also possible ?

Comment: I don't really get the point about "first six attempts failed"... because we know that Russia has a functional nuclear weapons, and has had since the 1950s. Russia isn't North Korea,

Comment: I am not sure whether they are telling the truth, but it should be at least theoretically possible to test a small bomb with a low enough yield to not be detected as a nuclear explosion (a suitcase bomb).

Comment: @JamesK "first six attempts failed" is his words, not mine.  He quite literally said it.

Comment: @JamesK re: "cannot be answered by a political science expert." Only if this requires a novel approach. If there is a standard approach, it would be part of knowledge about nuclear armaments. Which would make it a question about governments.

Comment: Just a couple of days, the youtube chanel *veritassium* released as new episode, [The Most Important Algorithm Of All Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmgFG7PUHfo) about FFT, the *fast* Fourier transformation.  The detection of underground tests of nuclear weapons indeed is one of the fields of application the video explains.

Comment: This would be a violation of the 1963 Test Ban Treaty, which is an argument for keeping the question open. Treaties are a cornerstone of international politics.

Comment: @MSalters the *1963 Test Ban Treaty* made an exception for underground tests; but this question is not asking about treaties. A *rephrased* general question is: *Is current technology sufficient to detect all nuclear weapons testing?* That question and the one asked are not suitable for Politics SE.

Comment: @MSalters The full name of the 1963 treaty was "[*Limited* Test Ban Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_explosion#Proliferation_Era)."  And it did not abandon underground tests.  The underground tests were not abandoned until the "[Comprehensive Nuclear Test Ban Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_Nuclear-Test-Ban_Treaty)" (1996), which is still not in effect because some of the signatories (namely the US) have not ratified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.   GPS satellites carry nuclear detonation detection capability.  The amount of radiation released in a burst can't be hidden.   Each GPS satellite picks up the radiation burst and timetags it very precisely.  Relatively simple math allows calculation of the blast location and an approximate yield.   It would be seen.   Whether it would be discussed publicly is another question.

There are other satellites and ground based monitors for exactly the same thing.  It wouldn't take long for everybody to know something happened and approximately where it occurred.

Edit : Search for "GPS nudet" on Google. Nudet stands for nuclear detection and is one of the core missions for the GPS satellite network from day #1.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence for your claim about GPS satellites?

Comment: @JoeW I was actually skeptic as well, but [the last bulletpoint under *Military* section on GPS on wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Military)confirms it. It would of course not be foolproof, and from the description an underground test need not be picked up.

Comment: @vidarlo Not saying I am skeptical of the concept, just that it is good to have supporting information about claims so people can better understand what is involved.

Comment: @JoeW I don't disagree :)

Comment: Sure.  Google the term "gps nudet".   Nudet means "Nuclear Detection".  You can't miss.  It is one of the core missions for the GPS satellite network from day #1.

Comment: @user2246302 at the very least, please, this search term to the answer.  If the comments get deleted (as they very well may be), anyone reading this answer will be left with nothing to go on.

Answer (score 17):

It is theoretically possible to do this, but no successful attempt has been generally disclosed. The way you'd go about it is:

- Test [underground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_nuclear_weapons_testing#Effects), since otherwise infra-sound and released gaseous isotopes will reveal that there's been a nuclear explosion.
- Test a very low-yield device, to reduce the seismic signal.
- Dig a very large cavity and suspend your test device in the centre of it. This should change the character of the seismic signal, which is otherwise distinctive.

This ought to work, but there are doubtless technical details that would matter. Unsurprisingly, the states whose nuclear weapons projects have studied them tend to keep quiet. [Forensic Seismology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_seismology) deals with the problems of detecting underground nuclear explosions.

It seems unlikely that the story is true. It would be a breach of Russian commitments to the [Comprehensive Nuclear-Test-Ban Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_Nuclear-Test-Ban_Treaty). That treaty is not (yet) in force, but doing a test would be seen as abandoning it, which would not go down well with non-nuclear states. That would make Putin's Russia even more of an outcast, without actually doing any good; everyone already knows Russia has lots of nuclear weapons.

The bit about a successful test after six failures makes it all less credible. The detonation of a [modern nuclear weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon_design) always starts by detonating conventional explosives to compress the fissionable materials. If the nuclear part does not go off, the weapon is wrecked. So it isn't an issue of shelf life and failures to go off at all, unless Russian nuclear designers have lost the ability to detonate *conventional* explosives reliably.

Sources: a lot of reading about nuclear weapons a couple of decades ago. I can't readily track down the references now.

Comment: And from your reading, what is the shelf life of an *unmaintained* nuclear warhead?  If you happen to remember anything that might be a clue.

Comment: Only if all seven attempts failed.

Comment: Is it possible to source the info about secret testing, or do you just know a lot about nuclear weapons?

Comment: @wrod: Updated answer for test ban treaty. A weapon could be designed for a shelf life of a few centuries, at the cost of weight and yield; an experimental one that was designed for high yield for its weight with no thought for durability might only last weeks.

Comment: @JamesK: Added a link on underground testing.

Comment: @Stančikas: added a paragraph about that.

Comment: The "6 failures" bit is not actually that unbelievable. The hypothetical device here is tiny, if only to be undetectable. It might be _too_ tiny: the conventional explosives could have exploded as intended, but the nuclear chain reaction might have fizzled. And if your goal is to make the smallest possible bomb, unnoticed, then it makes sense to start on the small side and scale up until it works.

Comment: @MSalters plus, if my crude understanding is correct, the precision needed in the implosion (and therefore in the conventional explosives) will be much greater for small devices - miniaturisation is always hard

Comment: "It is theoretically possible to do this, but no successful attempt has been generally disclosed"
Now that's the whole point of it, isn't it? I mean... if it was publicly known, then they failed to do it without anyone noticing.

Comment: "If the nuclear part does not go off, the weapon is wrecked. " - why does this make it unbelievable that there were 6 failures? Presumably they'd replace the weapon each time?

Comment: @komodosp: We can assume that the Russian nuclear weapons designers have access to the USSR's accumulated knowledge, even if they haven't done much designing recently. Needing seven tries to get a new design to detonate, with access to all that data, would imply a ludicrous degree of incompetence and of indulgence from the leadership. After about three failures, it should be clear that your designers don't know what they are doing, and thus should not be allowed to *set off nuclear explosions*, which is a rather dangerous activity.

Comment: Is the seismic signal really distinctive vs. non-nuclear explosives? (I can't see how it could be.) It seems like a sufficiently small explosion could be hidden in plain sight if you're doing it in a somewhat remote area that also has known mining activity, etc.

Comment: @user3067860 Seismic signals can differentiate between earthquake or bomb, but not what type of bomb. Bomb type is guessed based on magnitude, but verification is done with other methods. The smaller the bomb, the less likely to detect or identify. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_seismology

Comment: @DavidS rather than the amplitude, it probably requires looking at the actual shape of the wave.  Just like a different person pronouncing the same syllable at the same (normalized) amplitude will sound differently, so will 2 explosions produce a different wave shape.  A nuclear blast produces multiple "[generations](https://www.wisconsinproject.org/nuclear-weapons/)" of fission events, each one larger than the previous one.  Each generation creates compression for the next.  When it finally flies apart, each event must produce its own wave.

Answer (score 2):

Such tests may make sense if Russia wants to know how many of existing nuclear warheads still work. The warheads may be old and some maybe already past they "best before" date.

But there is no information about these tests anywhere in my media and I do not think the Western world would keep this secret if aware. It may have been partial tests with nuclear core removed, or just a very detailed technical inspection. Such are possible to keep secret.

Comment: The mental image of a nuclear weapon with "best before" stenciled on it is rather unsettling.

Comment: @Vorbis Some hydrogen bombs use tritium, which has a half-life time of only 12 years. So they require constant maintenance.

Comment: @Vorbishow about the mental image of a lot of these stenciled-in dates starting with 19XX ? Because that's the case, for a good chunk of the US arsenal as well.

Comment: @Vorbis, it would be worse if the stencil said "use by..."

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not the detonation could be performed without anybody noticing, there is another factor to consider: almost certainly, nuclear states closely monitor each other's facilities via satellite, and possibly agents on the ground. The USA has repeatedly stated that they did not see any indication of Russia using a nuclear weapon despite the sabre rattling during the war in Ukraine, so they clearly have that capability. I am sure any suspicious movement of personnel and equipment required for a nuclear test would not have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly was it that they were testing? Like for a nuclear bomb you usually have 2 sub-critical masses of uranium that you blast into each other with a conventional explosion to form a critical mass to trigger a nuclear chain reaction and a subsequent explosion. If you do that wrong you just have a conventional explosion that blasts nuclear material all over the place (dirty bomb).

So for example countries who are suspected of developing nukes need to map out the parameters of how to actually do that without just building dirty bombs and that's what they need tests for, as there are usually trade restrictions on getting then know-how, the explosives and the nuclear fuel (you either get one or the other or neither) and it's also a way to unofficially confirm that you have nukes as people are expected to see a successful test.

Russia is different though. They don't need that kind of testing as they already have established that technology decades ago and have a known large arsenal of nukes. So chances are they didn't actually explode nukes, what for? But that they tested whether their nukes are still operational, whether their carrier systems are still working, whether the chain of command is instructed and so on. Those are "nuclear tests" that are much easier to go down under the radar and could technically be called "testing their nuclear weapons" without needing a nuclear explosion which would likely be perceptible one way or another.

Comment: Nobody builds U235 bombs with "2 sub-critical masses of uranium" anymore (for various reasons); Hiroshima's Little Boy was the first and last one. All practical charges are implosive, and there is a lot that can go wrong with them. But you are right this was all ironed out long ago, and such charges could be tested without the actual Pu inside. Still, it has always been a pressing question how many of the warheads may fail in operational conditions. Not an insignificant percentage of ordinary weapon fail to explode, and they are much simpler.